# How to build sidekiq and rails image with docker?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, redis, docker, sidekiq

I am trying another way to build a rails application into a docker image.

The structure of my services:

- redis -- from official docker hub registry
- fluentd -- from official docker hub registry
- mysql -- from official docker hub registry
- sidekiq -- build myself(maybe there isn't a official image for this)
- web -- build myself

I created two Dockerfiles like:

- Dockerfile.sidekiq
- Dockerfile.web

Dockerfile.sidekiq

```
FROM ruby:2.2.2

ENV APP_HOME /myapp
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

ADD Gemfile $APP_HOME/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock $APP_HOME/Gemfile.lock
ADD config/sidekiq.yml $APP_HOME/config/sidekiq.yml
ADD init_sidekiq.sh $APP_HOME/

RUN export LANG=C.UTF-8 && bundle install

ADD . $APP_HOME

CMD ["sh", "init_sidekiq.sh"]
```

init_sidekiq.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
```

Dockerfile.web

```
FROM rails:4.2.1

ENV APP_HOME /myapp
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

ADD Gemfile $APP_HOME/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock $APP_HOME/Gemfile.lock
ADD init_web.sh $APP_HOME/

RUN export LANG=C.UTF-8 && bundle install

ADD . $APP_HOME

CMD ["sh", "init_web.sh"]
```

init_web.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate
bundle exec rails server -b 0.0.0.0
```

Use them I built two images:

- myapp_web
- myapp_sidekiq

Then run these containers:

```
$ docker run --name redis -d redis
$ docker run --name fluentd -d -p 24224:24224 fluent/fluentd
$ docker run --name mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my_password -d mysql
```

Make env.list

```
RAILS_ENV=production
DATABASE_URL=mysql2://root:my_password@172.17.0.4/myapp?checkout_timeout=20000
```

Go on run these containers:

```
$ docker run --name web -d -p 3000:3000 --link mysql:mysql --env-file ./env.list myapp_web
$ docker run --name sidekiq -d --link mysql:mysql --env-file ./env.list myapp_sidekiq
```

The result:

- redis -- success
- fluentd -- success
- mysql -- success
- web -- success
- sidekiq -- failure

The sidekiq log:

```
$ docker logs sidekiq
Unknown database 'myapp'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:23:in `rescue in mysql2_connection'
```

I used the same method both web and sidekiq to connect mysql. I believe that in the mysql container there exists a `myapp` database. But why it can't find it?

Is it a wrong way to make them been two containers? How to run sidekiq correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem there is how are you connecting to redis? The message appears to come from sidekiq and somehow it can't connect to your redis server. (and I think trying to connect to some bogus db server/database)

So I think you need to link your sidekiq container to both your db container and also your redis container.

```
docker run --name sidekiq -d --link mysql:mysql --link redis:redis --env-file ./env.list myapp_sidekiq
```

Also, would be nice if you can share your `env.list`

Comment: Thank you. I have did that follow you. And this time when I run `docker logs sidekiq`, there shows nothing. It worked? Is it necessary that I add `--link redis:redis` to run web container,too? By the way, I edited my question and added `env.list` file.

Comment: @scho can you test it out ? I think you can run a rails console container with the same config as your `web` container. Then send a mini sample background job.  See if it's getting processed by sidekiq.

Comment: When I run `docker exec web bundle exec rails c`, it showed: `Loading production environment (Rails 4.2.1) Switch to inspect mode.` Then exist.